# How to average and display values?

Tags: php, html, mysql

How can I calculate the average of column values in a mySQL table and display it in an HTML table?

```
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

$sql = 'SELECT AVG(price) FROM emp';
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
$values = mysql_num_rows($retval);

echo $values;
```

It returns 1. I feel like the problem is with mysql_num_rows() but what will be the correct code to display the average output?

Comment: `$values = mysql_fetch_array($retval);` ?

Comment: `mysql_num_rows()` is used to return the number of rows from a result set. If you want the actual *value*, you need to use a `mysql_fetch_*` function, such as `mysql_fetch_array()`, or `mysql_fetch_assoc()`. Also, I suggest you [enable error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/1438393) to see the error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = 'SELECT AVG(price) FROM emp';
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

$values = mysql_num_rows($retval);
echo $values;//it will display the number of rows of your resultant table

$avg=mysql_result($retval,0);

echo $avg;//it will show the average
```

**Dont use mysql_* as they are depracated.time to move on to mysqli_* or PDO.**